# MS Office Signature line provider add-in with SHA2

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, ms-office, add-in

I'm trying to create an MS Office Add-in for a signature line provider, using .NET Framework 3.5 to use it also to sign with SHA256/384/512 hash algorithms.

When I choose to load the add-in on SHA2 algorithms, I provide the GetProviderDetail() interface method the relevant hash strings when Office requests for it:

```
http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1
http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256 
http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#sha384
http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha512
```

My environment is mainly Windows 7 64 bit with office 32 and I experience some different behavior between Office 2010 64 bit and 32 bit and can't find any answer in MSDN or any other forum.

The problem is that my add-in doesn't load in the 32 bit Office environment. However, when I change it to SHA1 it work fine.

I suspected that there is a problem in the .NET Framework 2.0 - 3.5, but I doubt it.
I'm unable to change the project Framework to higher than 3.5, because it is a highly depended solution.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: When you say: it doesn't load, is it possible for you to get any output or logging?

Comment: In normal case(SHA1), I'm able to see my new signature provider in the "Insert" ribbon->"Signature line" in the Office with the "Microsoft Office Signature Line", but when I use SHA2 algorithms I don't see it